Deriving a "Clean"/Exogeneous Measure from an Independent Variable
Say I have a variable $y$ and a independent variable $\bar{x}$ (where $\bar{x}$ is a cross-sectional mean), I would like to come up with a new variable say $z = f(x)$ to perform a regression:
$$y = \alpha + \beta z$$
Seeing that $\bar{x}$ is good at explaining $y$, how can I be sure that the amount of $y$ that is explained by $z$ (also known as $\beta$ - correct me if I am wrong) is not already explained by $\bar{x}$?
Are there already formal tests that can be implemented to check for this and/or other regressions I can run or approaches I can implement to get what I want? (and thus answering the main question).
--- EDIT ---
The function z is given by the formula:
$$
z = f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1} \sum^N_{i=1}(x_i-\bar{x})}}{\bar{x}}
$$
where the standard deviation above is taken over a cross-section.

One ordinarily would do the usual testing of the significance of $z$ in the multiple regression model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2z;$ however, the validity of that would depend on how you determine $f.$  Please elaborate on your situation.

Hi @whuber, thank you for the helpful comments. I have made edits to reflect what I am specifically asking about, cheers.

Could you please explain how you would include $z,$ which is a scalar, in a regression where $x$ and $y$ are vectors?  Certainly $z$ does not qualify as a new variable like $x$ and $y$ are.

Hi @whuber, I apologise. This is a misrepresentation on my part. The variable $x$ is a panel variable, containing both cross-sectional and time series components. The variable $z$ is taken as the normalized standard deviation across the cross-section. I am asking if the normalized standard deviation $z$ is a clean measure (orthogonal) compared to $\bar{x}$. Another way of saying it is if the first and second moments are exogenous to each other in explaining $y$ (please forgive me if my wording is poor).
